# Loop through select statement and assign ids 1-16

Tags: t-sql, loops

I am looking to add a loop to my select statement and assign values 1-16 to my results.  after 16 I want the loop to start over at 1 and assign the next 1-16, etc. I am not sure if I can do this in a select statement, or if I should insert the rows incrementally into a temp table.  I would prefer to do it directly in a select statement if possible.  The result set can contain thousands of records.

Example:

```
RowDescription      AssignedID
Result 1                1
Result 2                2
Result 3                3
Result 4                4
Result 5                5
Result 6                6
Result 7                7
Result 8                8
Result 9                9
Result 10               10
Result 11               11
Result 12               12
Result 13               13
Result 14               14
Result 15               15
Result 16               16
Result 17               1
Result 18               2
Result 19               3
Result 20               4
Result 21               5
Result 22               6
Result 23               7
Result 24               8
Result 25               9
Result 26               10
Result 27               11
Result 28               12
Result 29               13
Result 30               14
Result 31               15
Result 32               16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description of the problem, you don't need to loop because you can get everything you want using the Row_Number function and a little bit of math.  In this case, just use the mod operator.  The +1 and -1 you see in the following script accommodates the 1 through 16 requirement.  The mod function would ordinarily return 0 to 15.

```
Select  RowDescription,
        (Row_Number() Over (Order BY RowDescription)-1) % 16 + 1 As AssignedId
From    YourTableName
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a method i could use with small sets, i'd say up to 10 thousand records could do fine

> select case when (select count(*) from items [x] where [x].item_id <
>   items.item_id) < 16 then  (select count(*) from items [x] where
>   [x].item_id < items.item_id) + 1 else  ((select count(*) from items
>   [x] where [x].item_id < items.item_id) % 16) + 1 end as counter, *
>   from items order by item_id

but it will be pretty slow for sure .. I suggest your other option should be of more help !